# How to download the full to-do (vue.js)list using JsPdf?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I am a beginner in this field. just try to do a small project using vue.js.
I wanted to give an option to users to download their Vue.js to-do list. I have had imported the jspdf library and Html2canvas.
[This is what I got as an output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xew3l.jpg)but [I want my output like this. (this is the output of my code in the local browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6r9N.png).try to find out my mistake here.

~my script method()here.

```js
  download() {
   const doc = new jsPDF();
   const width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
   const height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
   /** WITH CSS */
   var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    html2canvas(this.$refs.content, { canvas: canvasElement 
      }).then(function (canvas)
       {
    const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.8);
    doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',20,20 , width, height);
    doc.save("sample.pdf");
   });
   },
```

My Vue component code here

```Vue
<template>
<button @click="download">Download PDF WITH CSS</button>
  <div ref="content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center at-5">My Destinations</h2>
    <!-- input -->
    <div class="d-flex">

      
        <input v-model="task" type="text" placeholder="Enter Destination" class="form-control">
        <button @click="submitTask" class="btn btn-warning rounded-0">SUBMIT</button>

    </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered mt-5" id="tabalo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#33FDFF">Location</th>
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#33FDFF">Status</th>
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#33FDFF" class="text-center">#</th>
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#33FDFF" class="text-center">#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="background-color:#B895DE">
    <tr v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :key="index">
      <td>
        <span :class="{'visited': task.status === 'visited'}">{{task.name}}</span>
      </td>
      <td style = "width:100px">
        <span @click="changeStatus(index)" class="pointer"
        :class="{'text-danger' : task.status === 'to-visit',
        'text-warning' : task.status === 'at-the-moment',
        'text-success' : task.status === 'visited'}">
        {{ firstCharUpper (task.status)}}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button @click="editTask(index,task)" class="btn btn-warning rounded-0">Edit</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button @click="removeTask(index)" class="btn btn-warning rounded-0">Remove</button>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: These codes work well, but I got only part of the to-do list as a pdf. But I wanted to get a full to-do list as a pdf. pls, check uploaded images as well. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.
and it's working fine,[I could download the entire to-do list as pdf.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rFtt.png) but I have no idea wt went wrong on that js code. Just replace this code and give an id name for the part u wanted to get downloaded as pdf.

```js
download() {

    var dom = document.getElementById('tabalo'); //'tabalo' is an Id in my to-do list table
    html2canvas(dom).then(function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
        doc.save('mydestination.pdf');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

download() {

```
var dom = document.getElementById('tabalo'); //'tabalo' is an Id in my to-do list table
html2canvas(dom).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
    doc.save('mydestination.pdf');
});
this is working but when we have an image it not display the image
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).